# How do I decompress LZW packets from a network socket in python?

Tags: python, networking, compression

How do I inflate LZW packets? Is there a library?

Ive been trying to inflate and decode the National weather service EMWIN stream in python.

It requires packets to be unzipped from PKUNZIP format so it says.

I researched and found that PKZIP is close or is LZW. But I cant find any library to use this.

ZLIB is gzip which is LZ77 and Huffman coding
LZW library has no documentation that I can find
and this snippet I found requires the data be a list of some sort

This is what I have been working with so far. mind the tinkering

```
    import socket


sck = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sck.connect(("1.pool.iemwin.net", 2211))
sck.send("")

data = sck.recv(1116)
sck.close()



def decompress(compressed):
    """Decompress a list of output ks to a string."""
    from cStringIO import StringIO

    # Build the dictionary.
    dict_size = 256
    dictionary = dict((i, chr(i)) for i in xrange(dict_size))
    # in Python 3: dictionary = {i: chr(i) for i in range(dict_size)}

    # use StringIO, otherwise this becomes O(N^2)
    # due to string concatenation in a loop
    result = StringIO()
    w = chr(compressed.pop(0))
    result.write(w)
    for k in compressed:
        if k in dictionary:
            entry = dictionary[k]
        elif k == dict_size:
            entry = w + w[0]
        else:
            raise ValueError('Bad compressed k: %s' % k)
        result.write(entry)

        # Add w+entry[0] to the dictionary.
        dictionary[dict_size] = w + entry[0]
        dict_size += 1

        w = entry
    return result.getvalue()


new = decompress(data)
print new
```

The documentation for the whole protocol is this https://www.nws.noaa.gov/emwin/winpro.htm

^^^ That is pretty much all I could find

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my problem wasn't that it was compressed it was actually encoded.

It is XORed and then some packets are compressed not all of them.
The key to the xor is 0xFF and then you can use zlib to decompress the files

Moral of the story:
If for some reason someone encounters compressed packets and can't decompress them, try to see if they are encoded instead.

Thanks Jose Nieves

Answer (score 0):

The zipfile module handles PKZIP data (https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html)

Comment: I'm sure you're also aware of https://github.com/python-metar/python-metar

Comment: I don't see where I can process socket data im assuming is a string. Just files

Comment: Yes but I am more interested in processing EMWIN to get text products like hwo and weather alerts

Comment: "Other national data products, such as all surface observations (METARs) for a given hour, are first packed into one "file" and then compressed and transmitted.", ie. you should be able to trim zero-bytes and then treat the 1024 byte block as a file.